# Compilation error of Variable Length Array with GCC

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, variable-length-array

How to make a compilation successful for a program with a variable length array?(currently, Showing error : Variable sized array).  I am using gcc in linux. How to make compiler compatible to c99 standard ? PLease help me in this. THanks in advance.

Comment: With a new enough version of GCC it will automatically use a later version of the C standard. Which version are you using? What are you trying to do? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your code, together with a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of your errors (with comments added in the code where you get the errors).

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: it would have been faster to read the diagnostic message that tells you what to do, than write this question ...

Comment: @M.M Usually a VLA warning is just to hint that one uses VLAs in their code. It does not tell you what to do to satisfy the compiler. If you don't know what a VLA is nor what its advantages or disadvantages are you got a problem. Asking for that is absolutely appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

> **How to make compiler compatible to c99 standard?**

By default, the compiler defaults to the most compatible version of C version is installed. Do define the compilation version explicitly, compile the program with the following command-line:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -o my_program my_program.c
```

By defining the `-std=c99`, the compiler will be using `C99` standard.

**Edit:** If you're still getting the *warning* and not the *error*, then you need to provide your code to know what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Yes , I tried it . Still no changes in the result.  Thank You!!!

Comment: @DhanaPrakaash Then you need to show your code, we don't exactly know what your code does and the `-std=c99` flag must work correctly. Also, edit the question and add all the information after typing `gcc -v` command in your terminal.

Comment: @RohanBari Even with `-std=c99` the *warning* won't go away. The compiler is just hinting.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio the VLAs are supported in C99 standard, ain't it?

Comment: @RohanBari https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825661/why-does-clang-complain-about-using-variable-length-arrays-with-std-c99-flag

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio the question is tagged with `gcc` I guess. It's not clang.

Comment: @RohanBari It covers in the answers that any compiler can inform you about what it likes to do. I asked for clang, but the answers can be understood for any compiler for the *most* part.

Comment: @RohanBari It also explains why at OP's execution the presumed *error* does not go away -> "*Still no changes in the result*". I'm still a kind of confused about the "error" OP seems to get. The use of VLAs shouldn't cause any *error*.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yes, that's obviously not an error. I simply answered - *how to make compiler compatible to c99 standard* and that's the possible method to remove the VLA warning. However, I already asked for some code from the OP in order to understand what's actually going on.

Comment: @RohanBari I got nothing against your answer. It could have been highly possible that the use of `-std=c99` had removed the warning. I just try to find out what is going on here. Yes, the missing code is unfortunate and disadvantageous.

Comment: @RohanBari Also your answer answers perfectly: "*How to make compiler compatible to c99 standard?*" - Maybe you should emphasize this and separate with that both questions.

Answer (score 0):

> "*How to make a compilation successful for a program with a variable length array? (currently, Showing error : Variable sized array).*"

Usually it isn't an *error* to compile a code with a VLA unless you compile with `-Werror` flag.

The diagnostic you get is high-probably "only" a *warning* that you use a VLA inside of it, which is risky.

Thus, the compiler informs you about that.

So, you indeed *can* compile a program with VLAs without any error.

If you got errors they must belong to anything else. We can't find those out since you showed no specific code.

Take a look at this question of mine, not so long ago (even if it is for Clang, it covers the same topic as the answers suggest that a compiler is free to complain about whatever it likes):

[Why does clang complain about using variable-length arrays with '-std=c99' flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825661/why-does-clang-complain-about-using-variable-length-arrays-with-std-c99-flag)

All useful information you can find there.

VLAs are not portable. Try to use alternatives, for example dynamically allocated arrays by using `malloc()`.

Related:

- [malloced array VS. variable-length-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672322)
- [Is there any overhead for using variable-length arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034712)
- [Is it a good idea to use C99 VLA compared to malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082126)

---

> "*How to make compiler compatible to (the) C99 standard?*"

As Rohan in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62749665/12139179) already said, you can use the `-std-c99` flag at the invocation of gcc for that. But it probably won't solve your problem to do so.